# Got an correlation error when i am activate the webpart feature on central Admin

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, command

I created one WebPart by using Visual Studio 2010. After Creating this I deployed to the Central Admin.When I deployed it to the Central Admin, It deployed only in globally not for particular web application. I use the Powershell command to Deploy the Web part in central Admin.

The command is:

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity <SolutionName> -WebApplication <URLname>
```

This is the command i used to deploy the webpart.

For this i got an error like:

> "This solution contains no resources scoped for a Web application and cannot be deployed to a particular Web application."

This is one problem.And another thing is:

When I am deployed the Web part as Globally. It is successfully deployed but when i activate the webpart feature in Central Admin It got an Correralation ID error. The same error is also occured when i am activate the feature in the web application.

What is the reason for that?

Comment: If you are getting an Correlation ID then copy that ID and search in the ULS Logs for the actual error description that should help you.  If you are not able to solve this by yourself then post the error logs relating to the correlation token id.

Answer (score 0):

Does the deployment work if you deploy it at the farm level?